# XNA Creating a custom ModelProcessor

Tags: 3d, xna

I'm trying to follow [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2006/12/07/rendering-a-model-with-a-custom-effect.aspx) tutorial but I'm getting errors when trying to implement it.

For the lines `using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors;`
its telling me: `Error  3   The type or namespace name 'Pipeline' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Every class I try to use is highlighted and telling me something like: `Error   8   The type or namespace name 'ModelProcessor' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline.Processors;

// TODO: replace these with the processor input and output types.
using TInput = System.String;
using TOutput = System.String;
using System.IO;

namespace Game.Engine
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class will be instantiated by the XNA Framework Content Pipeline
    /// to apply custom processing to content data, converting an object of
    /// type TInput to TOutput. The input and output types may be the same if
    /// the processor wishes to alter data without changing its type.
    ///
    /// This should be part of a Content Pipeline Extension Library project.
    ///
    /// TODO: change the ContentProcessor attribute to specify the correct
    /// display name for this processor.
    /// </summary>
    [ContentProcessor]
    public class CustomEffectModelProcessor : ModelProcessor
    {
        protected override MaterialContent ConvertMaterial(MaterialContent material, ContentProcessorContext context)
        {
            EffectMaterialContent myMaterial = new EffectMaterialContent();

            string effectPath = Path.GetFullPath("MyEffect.fx");

            myMaterial.Effect = new ExternalReference<EffectContent>(effectPath);

            return base.ConvertMaterial(myMaterial, context);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you take the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb447754.aspx#ID4E3C) to set up a content pipeline extension library? Are you referencing the proper assembly? (Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.Pipeline)

Comment: I didn't follow the steps. Thanks for the link, I'm new so there is a lot of stuff I can miss. I'll try it out and come back to tell if it worked :)